# Starting a remote MySQL server using php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, centos

I currently use a VPS hosting MySQL to help reduce the load of my main server. Occasionally the SQL server conks out due to the amount of traffic it receives.

I'd like a small PHP script that will start the remote server. I already have a way of detecting when the SQL server isn't available, I just need a way of executing `/etc/init.d/mysql start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [rexec command](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rexec.htm)